# Can ANDROID access or use an IP GPS, hosted from GPSd in Linux

Tags: android, linux, gpsd

I have an Android tablet. It does not have a GPS. Is it possible to have the ANDROID tablet use a shared IP GPS provided by GPSd from Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An android tablet without GPS is kind of a strange device.  But for an answer-  with a custom ROM, sure.  You could add a location provider, even name it as the GPS provider so requesting GPS would get that.  Without a custom ROM, no.  But the NETWORK provider should still work based on wifi/cellular networks.

Answer (score 0):

Gabe,

thank you for taking the time to answer my question. It was what I expected. Its a shame as I wish I access an IP based GPSd service. Originally I was trying to find a rugged bluetooth gps for an android tablet. But one does not exist.

All the best
Dave